# How can I find the smallest value in a Perl hash of hashes of arrays?

Tags: perl, data-structures, sorting

I want to find the easiest way of finding the hash values

```
City {
  city1 -> Street1 -> [ high_street , 2]
           street2 -> [ low_street , 2]
  city2 -> Street1 -> [ high_street1 , 2]
           street2 -> [ low_street2 , 2]
  city3 -> Street1 -> [ high_street1 , 1]
           street2 -> [ low_street2 , 1]
}
```

This structure is sorted into a hash.  How do I find the smallest value of the second elements of the arrays inside the second level of hashes?

I am expecting my smallest value to be - City3, street 1 - highstreet 1. This based on last value which is avilable at only one time.  But 2 elements in the array has 1 times.  But I just want to know first element first.

Is there any easy to find it?

Comment: According to what scale is City 3, street 1, highstreet 1 the smallest value? You can sort hashes, and even complex hash of hashes, via Perl's `sort`, but for something like this, you need to define *how* the `sort` function should evaluate items. What is 'smaller' and what 'larger' in this context?

Comment: As a start, see `perldoc -q sort` which will show you some entries from Perl's FAQ on sorting.

Comment: city 3, street 1, highstreet 1 the smallest value because it got '1' Time . and street 2 also 1 time only . but i just want to first element of that array

Comment: i don't want to do any sorting . i just to find the smallest value.

Comment: '1' Time? You never mention this anywhere in your question. How is "Time" computed? Were we supposed to know that?

Comment: acutally the no (1,2 ) is no of homes in street

Comment: There is no "first" element of the hash.  Hashes are unordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $City = {
    city1 => {
        Street1 => [ 'high_street', 2],
        street2 => [ 'low_street', 2],
    },
    city2 => {
        Street1 => [ 'high_street1', 2],
        street2 => [ 'low_street2', 2],
    },
    city3 => {
        Street1 => [ 'high_street1', 1],
        street2 => [ 'low_street2', 1],
    },
};

my $smallest_key1;
my $smallest_key2;
my $smallest_value;
foreach my $key1 (keys %{$City}) {
    foreach my $key2 (keys %{$City->{$key1}}) {
        if(not defined $smallest_value or $City->{$key1}{$key2}[1] < $smallest_value) {
             $smallest_key1 = $key1;
             $smallest_key2 = $key2;
             $smallest_value = $City->{$key1}{$key2}[1];
        }
    }
}
print 'Smallest: ', $smallest_key1, ', ', $smallest_key2, ', ', join(', ', @{$City->{$smallest_key1}{$smallest_key2}}), "\n";
```

Comment: Sometimes your mind-reading abilities scare the hell out of me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be here all week.  Tip your waitress, she works hard.